# Can 'than who' be safely used now?

Tags: grammaticality

Page 1 of 2 of http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/than-i-versus-than-me:

> However, a thorn in the side of conjunctionists is the phrase than whom; both sides of the debate agree **than who** just sounds wrong and recommend **than whom** in all cases, as in the question "*You were faster than whom?*"
>
> ..."Since avoiding ambiguity awards a point to the conjunctionists"

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=than+who%2C+than+whom&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthan%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthan%20whom%3B%2Cc0) displays the predominance of **than whom** until around 1980, when the trend reversed.

1. How and why does "**than who** just sounds wrong"? "Since ... conjunctionvists", I prefer **than who**.
2. Has **than who** become (cogently and validly) dignified and usable? Why or why not?

Comment: Most of the matching sentences in the Google Books data won't end after "than who".  Be careful not to misinterpret the data.

Comment: *"You were faster than whom?"* <== That sounds weird to me. I'll be giving that speaker a look-over, to see where he might be originating from, or to see if he's a prankster, or if he's a foreign spy, or if he's a space creature masquerading as a human (an advance scout for an alien invasion). -- I hope you will eventually realize that your link goes to a terrible "grammar" site, a site that is full of bad info.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the context. In formal speech writing, you probably still need "than whom". In informal speech and writing, "than who" isn't going to annoy anybody who isn't *trying* to be annoyed.